# PhpStorm Show errors with the word 'DESC' in a correct MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I have several MySQL queries that work, but my IDE (PhpStorm) shows an error about the word `DESC`

[image]

Why ? How can I fix this without switching off this kind of error in settings.

Comment: your query seems a bit strange to mee because it would not be possible to use variables for the name of database objects such as table or column names.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to change like this {$wpdb->posts}... but the problem is still at the end of the query.

Comment: Does mysql let you order by columns that are not part of the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a parser issue. Don't split `$post_type` and `$extra_checks`, have them on the same line and it would look alright:

[image: huh]

You might want to report this at [JetBrains tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes) to get it fixed in future versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot... notice if i write {$a->post} or for my example {$wpdb->posts}, it gets a new error.